# Ether Drake Hatchling / Dragonscale Armor with Habitat

Tags: stellaris

According to the wiki page https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Spaceborne_aliens#Ether_Drake

> The planet it guarded, Dragon's Hoard, is a very wealthy planet with
>   +30 Energy and Minerals. Putting a mining station on it will eventually provide two special rewards (MTTH 600 months): Enable
>   researching of Tech Artificial Dragonscales, the only
>   Level 6 Armor. Discover a Dragon Egg and get the option to smash it
>   for 300 Influence or issue a special project to incubate the egg and
>   hatch a Young Drake. The Young Drake has between 14k and 16k fleet
>   power.

My question is if you build a habitat on the Dragon's Hoard instead of a mining station, is it still possible to get the Artificial Dragonscales tech or the Ether drake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it has to be a mining station.

But nothing is stopping you getting a habitat up once they fire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm accepting this, and also warning people not to build a habitat on the dragon's hoard until at least the armor fires as AFAIK habitats can't be dismantled. The baby drake is meh, but the T6 armor is worth getting.